# Make the most recently open currently open buffer on top of the Buffers list with helm-mini

Tags: helm

It seems `helm-mini` places the currently open buffer on the bottom of the `Buffers` list.

For example, suppose I have a two splits and `test.txt` is open in one of them. Sometimes I want to open `test.txt` in the current split, and when I do `helm-mini`, the `test.txt` is on the bottom of the list (even though it is the most recently opened one), which makes selecting that file inconvenient.

I was wondering if there is any way to put it on the top of the list - or at least in the order of recency. It seems like `helm-mini` sorts buffers in the most recent order, except the currently visible one in one of the splits.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstoop your example, but when I call `split-window-right` it opens that same buffer in the other window, so if done it from `test.txt`, isn't that it already open in both windows? Also, since `helm-mini`'s main (only?) purpose is to switch buffers, I guess the logic of having the currently open buffer at the bottom is that it is generally the least likely buffer you would want to switch to. However, if you are using `helm-mini` to e.g., glance at what buffers are open, and then want to continue working in the current buffer,  how about `C-g` to close `helm-mini`?

Comment: You are right - thank you. I edited the question so it is more clear. The main issue is that when I have one file open in one of the splits, it seems `helm-mini` always put that file on the bottom of the list (or at least not in top 10 or whatever).

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem seems to happen when I split, switch buffers, and then want to switch back to the most recent buffer, but now it is at the bottom of the list. This sounds like a bug to me, because it is not the way `helm-mini` works before the split. Am I right in assuming that `helm-mini` works the way you want it to *before* you split windows?

Comment: You are right. It actually does the same thing - it puts the current buffer at the bottom of the list, which makes sense since you would want to switch to another buffer in that case. I think the problem is that `helm-mini` treats the buffer which is active in the other split as the current buffer and put it on the bottom.

Comment: Maybe I should open an issue on helm project. :)

Comment: If you don't get a good solution here within a few days, I think that is a good idea

Comment: Done (https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1301).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will fix this (thanks to thierryvolpiatto):

```
(defun helm/modify-ido-temp-list ()
  (let ((bl (mapcar #'buffer-name (buffer-list (selected-frame)))))
    (setq ido-temp-list (append (cdr bl) (list (car bl))))))

(add-hook 'ido-make-buffer-list-hook 'helm/modify-ido-temp-list)
```

(See https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1301)