# Make the most recently visited buffer on top of the Buffers list with switch-to-buffer under helm

Tags: buffers, helm, menu-bar

When I do `C-x b` under `helm` the topmost buffer in the list is the most recently visited buffer *except* if another window is currently visiting that buffer.

How can I make the topmost buffer be the most recently visited buffer regardless of whether another is currently visiting it (and more generally, make the sort order of the buffer list be by most recent visitation time first regardless of other visiting windows)?

I have found historical answers to this question but they don't seem to work with modern `helm`:

- [Make the most recently open currently open buffer on top of the Buffers list with helm-mini](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19069/make-the-most-recently-open-currently-open-buffer-on-top-of-the-buffers-list-wit)
- https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2jzkz7/quickly_switch_to_previous_buffer/

Comment: The user cannot entirely control the global or frame-local buffer-list.  If the order is essential, then a separate list would need to be maintained and programmatically combed as needed to remove dead/killed buffers from the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the most recently open currently open buffer on top of the Buffers list with helm-mini](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19069/make-the-most-recently-open-currently-open-buffer-on-top-of-the-buffers-list-wit)

Comment: Lack of good answers is not a reason to add a duplicate question. Instead, post a comment on the original answers, to say that they don't work with XYZ version of ABC. And be specific about what "don't work" means.